# Estimation of population quantile based on mutually exclusive sub-populations?

Tags: estimation, quantiles

I have read somewhere that "it's obvious" that the estimator $\hat{q}\%$ where $q\%$ is the `q`-quantile% of a $X_i  iid \tilde{ } Dn$ for some distribution $Dn$ for $i = 1...n$ for some $n$

Consider a partition of the $X_i$ into $k$ mutually exclusive groups.

How do you estimate $q$ where you are only allowed to use $X_i$ together if they belong to the same group.

For example, if you are interested in the `median` of $Dn$ then you can't estimate it using `median(X_i)` because you are using $X_i$ from different groups together.

You estimate `median` using `median` of each group, then taking the median.

E.g.

$\hat{median} Dn = median(median(X_i over\ i\ \text{belong to group k}) \ \text{over}\ k)$

By extension (and this is where the claim of "obvious" is)

$\hat{q}\% Dn = q(q(X_i over\ i\ \text{belong to group k}) \ \text{over}\ k)$

Basically says, if you want to estimate quantile-`q`, then take quantile-`q` of each group, then take the quantile `q` of the results to arrive at your estimate. This is meant to be an unbiased estaimtor the population `quantile`.

The use case in distributed data algorithms, where we have a map-step and we can use sub-groups of data to estimate something, then all the sub-group estimates are carried over to a master node in a reduce stop to arrive at the final estimates.

Where can I find a proof of the obvious claim?